# « Nous vous avons » ou « Nous avons vous »

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, ordre-des-mots

J'hésite entre deux possibilités. Je pense que la première est correcte mais je veux être sûr qu'on peut l'utiliser.

- Nous vous avons déjà donné un crédit pour un mois de service.
- Nous avons vous déjà donné un crédit pour un mois de service.

Comment: donner un crédit doesn't sound very French to me. Is this for a retail store?

Comment: Not really, but the charges were billed he didn't pay for them. Otherwise I would've used  reimbursement but I don't really think it applies

Comment: @Lambie French-Canadian here. I'm not offended by "Donner un crédit". You can often hear "Un crédit en magasin" in the context of reimbursement given in the form of store credit. This might be an anglicism, however.

Comment: Telephone charges? Utilities charges? En France, on parle de trop perçu reporté sur la prochaine facture. On n'utilise pas l'idée d'un crédit. Enfin, tout dépend de l'industrie.....https://particuliers.engie.fr/questions-reponses/factures-contrat/facture.html

Comment: Valider _porter au crédit d'un compte_ (les sommes) ; ou parle-t-on au final d'un _rabais_...

Comment: I totally agree with all of you :) I just don't know what else to use & credit does sound a bit awkward

Answer (score 1):

En effet, c'est le premier qui est correct :

> Nous vous avons déjà donné ...

Answer (score 1):

Le premier est correct, parce que l'objet indirect, direct, et les pronoms adverbiaux précèdent toujours le verbe auxiliaire. (**Note:** L'impératif  est differente, car les verbes précèdent en ce cas)

Voici des exemples:

1)

> Ce n'est pas comme ça que je t'ai appris à fermer une porte !

2)

> ...qu'il m'ait employé.

3)

> Je t'en ai dit.

4)

> Nous leur avons acheté un chocolat liégois.

5)

> Il me les a donnés quand il m'y a emmené.

Parce que ma langue maternelle n'est pas le français, mais l'anglais, ainsi il faut que je pense parfois à l'ordre des verbes et la formulation de mes phrases.

**1) Cherchez le verbe auxiliaire et souvenez-vous l'ordre des pronoms objets indirects, directs, et pronoms adverbiaux.**

**2) Mettez-les devant les verbes.**

Comment: Pas toujours… Ta dernière phrase est un parfait exemple d'impératif où les pronoms viennent après le verbe :-)

Comment: Tout à fait d'accord ;)

Answer (score 1):

**la première est correcte:**

> Nous vous avons déjà donné un crédit pour un mois de service.

**La seconde est incorrecte:**

Car les **pronoms** se placent **avant** le verbe (principal ou auxiliaire), **sauf à l'impératif ou à l'interrogatif**:

> Nous te voyons ...  (COD : toi)
>
> Nous nous lavons ... (pronom réfléchi)
>
> Nous lui parlons ...  (COI: à lui)
>
> Nous en parlons ... (COI : de cela)
>
> Nous y allons ... ( COI : à cet endroit)
>
> Nous le lui disons ... (COD + COI)

Answer (score 1):

La première phrase est en effet correcte :

> Nous vous avons déjà donné un crédit pour un mois de service.

Remarque : Même si `donner` est valide, j'utiliserais plutôt le verbe `accorder` ([L'internaute](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/accorder/), sens 1) pour parler d'un crédit :

> Nous vous avons déjà accordé un crédit pour un mois de service.

Comment: Cette réponse ne sert que pour la remarque. Les autres ont déjà bien répondu à la question, mais je n'ai pas assez de réputation pour commenter sur leurs posts :).

Answer (score -5):

```
    1 : Nous vous avons déjà donné un crédit pour un mois de service
```

This one is correct if you want to tell the client he's already got a credit for the month .

```
    2 : Nous avons vous déjà donné un crédit pour un mois de service
```

This one is correct if you want to *ask* like " Did we already gave you the monthly credit ? " but you'll have to put a "-" like this :

```
Nous avons-vous déjà donné un crédit pour un mois de service ?
```

Comment: -1 : pour vérifier une tournure douteuse : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Nous+avons-vous%2C%22vous+avons-nous+fait%22&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=

Comment: [Ici](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Nous+avons-vous&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnous%20avons%20-%20vous%3B%2Cc0) tu pourra constater que l'expression existe et est utilisée. C'est pas parce que tu l'as manquée dans ta réponse qu'il faut mettre -1 =)

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Nous+avons-vous%2C+vous+avons-nous+fait&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvous%20avons%20-%20nous%20fait%3B%2Cc0 était ma première interrogation (ce n'est pas celle donnée en commentaire), où il y a les deux formules. *Nous avez-vous déjà donné ...* serait correct, mais ce ne sont plus les même débiteurs/créditeurs. Je ne sais pas comment trouver les textes d'où sont extraits votre requête Ngram.

Comment: pour garder le même sens, on pourrait dire: Vous avons-nous ...

Comment: Si vous effacez votre question avec un score à -3, vous bénéficierez d'un badge 'Peer Pressure'.